# How to make every added items in my 'list view', clickable and can open up a new activity

Tags: android, android-listview

i'm trying to make every items added in my 'list view', clickable and can open up a new activity to display some details. I couldn't find  where the 'items' are since it is not there yet.( I need to insert data to make it shows up to my 'list view'.

```
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.supplyrecordslistview);


    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();


    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(SupplyRecords.this, "Batch List Is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

}

public void openMainActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openInputSupply(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InputSupply.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: implement listview.setOnItemclickListener();

Comment: ask if you want example